# iOS: UITableView cell changes selection state when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I am not sure how to write a simple title which explains my problem.

I got a UITableView on my screen. As long as the table view is smaller than the screen (all cells fits on the screen without scrolling) everything is fine. However as soon as the user needs to scroll the screen to find a cell which is on the bottom of the table, some cells randomly changes their selection state.
I implemented the UITableView like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"";

    switch (indexPath.section)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            if (indexPath.row == 0)
            {
                simpleTableIdentifier = @"EventDateCell";
            }
            else
            {
                simpleTableIdentifier = @"EventDateSelectCell";
            }

            [...]

            return cell;
        }break;

        case 2:
        {
            simpleTableIdentifier = @"SelectPlayerCell";

            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil)
            {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            }

            Player *player = [self.playerController getPlayerAtPosition:indexPath.row];

            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", player.persistentData.name];

            return cell;
        }break;

        default:
        {
            simpleTableIdentifier = @"EventNameCell";

            [...]

            return cell;
        }break;
    }
}
```

Does xCode change the indexPath.row according to the cells that are shown on the screen?

The code to mark a selected cell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0)
    {
       [..]
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        // close date picker if it is still open
        if (self.selectingEventDate == TRUE)
        {
           [...]
        } 

        if(self.createdEvent != nil)
        {
            if ([[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
            {
                [self tableView:tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            }
            else
            {
                [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelected:TRUE];
                [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

                [self.eventController addPlayerToEvent:self.createdEvent :[self.playerController getPlayerAtPosition:indexPath.row]];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0)
    {
       [...]
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        if(self.createdEvent != nil)
        {
            [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelected:FALSE];
            [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

            [self.eventController removePlayerFromEvent:self.createdEvent :[self.playerController getPlayerAtPosition:indexPath.row] :FALSE];
        }
    }
}
```

I found out: If the first cell is marked, there are 12 cells that are displayed correctly and the 13th is checked.

Comment: Check my answer it working in my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only change the cell's appearance in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  If you make changes elsewhere, they will be applied to the cached cells that are returned to you by `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.

In this case, give the player a "selected" attribute, set it when you need to, and call `reloadData`.  In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` use that attribute to set the cell selection state.

Comment: wont this slow the program down?

Comment: Not in any noticeable way.  The reload only affects visible cells, so you're only looking at refreshing 12 cells.

Comment: (And since you're using the player object to provide cell data for other things, it's nicer to keep the information there than to juggle multiple arrays.)

Answer (score 5):

First of all you take an Array which is store the value when you select the Cell and remove the value when click on second time of cell.

**In ViewController.h file**

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *arySelectionState;

**In ViewController.m file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    arySelectionState = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 }
```

## pragma mark - TableView delegate

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    custom_Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellDetails" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    if ([arySelectionState containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:indexPath.row]])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    }



    [cell.labtest setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lable_%ld",(long)indexPath.row]];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if ([arySelectionState containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:indexPath.row]])
    {

        [arySelectionState removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:indexPath.row]];

        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
    else
    {

        [arySelectionState addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:indexPath.row]];

        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }


}
```

ITS WORKING FINE ......